# htttpwebrequest from textfile

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

I have this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://10.123.9.66:80/solr_3.6/wiewaswie_live/select/?qt=edismax_nosyn_a2aperson&q=(huibert faro)&fq={!tag%3Dalldoctypes}doc_type:1&facet.query={!ex%3Dalldoctypes}doc_type:3 AND (b_public:1 OR fk_account:(10847871))&facet.query={!ex%3Dalldoctypes}doc_type:2 AND (b_public:1 OR fk_account:(10847871))&spellcheck=true&spellcheck.count=-3&start=10&sort=name_last asc, score desc&omitHeader=true");

    System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
    timer.Start();

    TimeSpan timeTaken = timer.Elapsed;

    try
    {
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        timer.Stop();
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(exception.Message);
    }

    try
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("testSolar.txt"))
        {
            String line = sr.ReadToEnd();
            txtReadFile.Text = timeTaken.ToString();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read:");
        Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
    }
}
```

But the: `HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create` is now hard coded. But I have a text file with many request, like this:

```
http://10.123.9.66:80/solr_3.6/wiewaswie_live/select/   qt=standard_a2aperson&q=*:*&fq=(nosyn_name_last_exact:(qxqroelofqxq))&fq=(nosyn_name_patronym_exact:(qxqharmsqxq))&spellcheck.q=(qxqroelofqxq qxqharmsqxq)&fq={!tag%3Dalldoctypes}doc_type:1&fq=date_main:[0 TO 18133112]&facet.query={!ex%3Dalldoctypes}doc_type:3 AND (b_public:1)&facet.query={!ex%3Dalldoctypes}doc_type:2 AND (b_public:1)&spellcheck=true&spellcheck.count=-3&start=0&sort=name_last asc, score desc&omitHeader=true
http://10.123.9.66:80/solr_3.6/wiewaswie_live/select/   qt=edismax_nosyn_a2aperson&q=(arie  van Hattum)&fq={!tag%3Dalldoctypes}doc_type:1&fq=(fk_collectiontype:6)&fq=(fk_eventrole:63)&fq=date_main:[18430000 TO 19513112]&facet.query={!ex%3Dalldoctypes}doc_type:3 AND (b_public:1)&facet.query={!ex%3Dalldoctypes}doc_type:2 AND (b_public:1)&spellcheck=true&spellcheck.count=-3&start=0&sort=name_last asc, score desc&omitHeader=true
http://10.123.9.66:80/solr_3.6/wiewaswie_live/select/   qt=edismax_nosyn_a2aperson&q=(huibert faro)&fq={!tag%3Dalldoctypes}doc_type:1&facet.query={!ex%3Dalldoctypes}doc_type:3 AND (b_public:1 OR fk_account:(10847871))&facet.query={!ex%3Dalldoctypes}doc_type:2 AND (b_public:1 OR fk_account:(10847871))&spellcheck=true&spellcheck.count=-3&start=10&sort=name_last asc, score desc&omitHeader=true
http://10.123.9.66:80/solr_3.6/wiewaswie_live/select/   qt=edismax_nosyn_a2aperson&q=(huibert faro)&fq={!tag%3Dalldoctypes}doc_type:1&facet.query={!ex%3Dalldoctypes}doc_type:3 AND (b_public:1 OR fk_account:(10847871))&facet.query={!ex%3Dalldoctypes}doc_type:2 AND (b_public:1 OR fk_account:(10847871))&spellcheck=true&spellcheck.count=-3&start=10&sort=name_last asc, score desc&omitHeader=true
http://10.123.9.66:80/solr_3.6/wiewaswie_live/select/   qt=edismax_nosyn_a2aperson&q=(ickson)&fq={!tag%3Dalldoctypes}doc_type:1&facet.query={!ex%3Dalldoctypes}doc_type:3 AND (b_public:1)&facet.query={!ex%3Dalldoctypes}doc_type:2 AND (b_public:1)&spellcheck=true&spellcheck.count=-3&start=0&sort=name_last asc, score desc&omitHeader=false&echoParams=EXPLICIT
http://10.123.9.66:80/solr_3.6/wiewaswie_live/select/   qt=edismax_nosyn_a2aperson&q=(ickson)&fq={!tag%3Dalldoctypes}doc_type:1&facet.query={!ex%3Dalldoctypes}doc_type:3 AND (b_public:1)&facet.query={!ex%3Dalldoctypes}doc_type:2 AND (b_public:1)&spellcheck=true&spellcheck.count=-3&start=0&sort=name_last asc, score desc&omitHeader=false&echoParams=EXPLICIT
http://10.123.9.66:80/solr_3.6/combi_live/select/   qt=standard_a2aperson&q=(((((nosyn_name_last_b_exact:(qxqkuilenburgqxq))))))&fq=(nosyn_name_last_exact:(qxqbroekqxq))&spellcheck.q=(qxqbroekqxq  kuilenburg)&fq=(fk_collectiontype:6)&spellcheck=true&spellcheck.count=-3&start=10&sort=date_main asc, score desc&omitHeader=true
http://10.123.9.66:80/solr_3.6/combi_live/select/   qt=standard_a2aperson&q=(((((nosyn_name_last_b_exact:(qxqkuilenburgqxq))))))&fq=(nosyn_name_last_exact:(qxqbroekqxq))&spellcheck.q=(qxqbroekqxq  kuilenburg)&fq=(fk_collectiontype:6)&spellcheck=true&spellcheck.count=-3&start=10&sort=date_main asc, score desc&omitHeader=true
http://10.123.9.66:80/solr_3.6/combi_live/select/   qt=standard_a2aperson&q=(((((nosyn_name_last_b_exact:(qxqkruijsqxq))))))&fq=(nosyn_name_first_exact:(qxqw*qxq))&fq=(nosyn_name_last_exact:(qxqtreurenqxq))&spellcheck.q=(qxqw*qxq qxqtreurenqxq  kruijs)&spellcheck=true&spellcheck.count=-3&start=0&sort=date_main asc, score desc&omitHeader=true
http://10.123.9.66:80/solr_3.6/combi_live/select/   qt=standard_a2aperson&q=(((((nosyn_name_last_b_exact:(qxqkruijsqxq))))))&fq=(nosyn_name_first_exact:(qxqw*qxq))&fq=(nosyn_name_last_exact:(qxqtreurenqxq))&spellcheck.q=(qxqw*qxq qxqtreurenqxq  kruijs)&spellcheck=true&spellcheck.count=-3&start=0&sort=date_main asc, score desc&omitHeader=true
```

And so from each http I want to see the response time in the textbox(): `txtReadFile.Text = timeTaken.ToString();`

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried anything other than hard coding the url?  A quick google would give you an answer on how to open and read a file.

Comment: Yes, I already know how to read a file: using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("testSolar.txt"))
                {
                    String line = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    txtReadFile.Text = timeTaken.ToString();
                }

Comment: But what will be then  HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you are using the `StopWatch` class wrong.  You are supposed to start it, stop it and then get the elapsed time.

Next, if you are trying to read the file and use the urls in that file, then you would need to read the file *first* and then try to connect to the urls.

Below is what I believe you want, as a console app.  If you want to use it in a WinForm application, you can easily use the `Dictionary<string, TimeSpan>` to populate a datagrid or listview for more friendly viewing interface.

```
//Consider making this configurable
const string sourceFile = @"testSolar.txt";

var requester = new WebClient();
var times = new Dictionary<string, TimeSpan>();
var stopwatch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();

//Add header so if headers are tracked, it will show it is your application rather than something ambiguous
requester.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, "Response-Tester-Client");

var urlList = new List<string>();

//Loop through the lines in the file to get the urls to hit against
try
{
    stopwatch.Start();
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(sourceFile))
    {

        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            urlList.Add(reader.ReadLine());
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("An error occured while attempting to access the source file at {0}", sourceFile);
}
finally
{
    //Stop, record and reset the stopwatch
    stopwatch.Stop();
    times.Add("FileReadTime", stopwatch.Elapsed);
    stopwatch.Reset();
}

//Try to connect to each url
var counter = 1;
foreach (var url in urlList)
{
    try
    {
        stopwatch.Start();
        requester.DownloadString(url);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("An error occured while attempting to connect to {0}", url);
    }
    finally
    {
        stopwatch.Stop();

        //We use the counter for a friendlier url as the current ones are unwieldly
        times.Add("Url " + counter, stopwatch.Elapsed);
        counter++;

        stopwatch.Reset();
    }
}

//Release the resources for the WebClient 
requester.Dispose();

//Write the response times
foreach (var key in times.Keys)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", key, times[key].TotalSeconds);
}
```

Comment: Hi Justin, Thank you very much!! But I have some other questions.

Comment: Can I sent you email? My email is: niels.fischereinie@gmail.com

Comment: But in the http line the extra space also have to be removed, and before qt there has to be standing an ?, I try it like this: while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        urlList.Add(reader.ReadLine());
                        urlList.Remove("\n");

                    }

Comment: url.Replace("\n", string.Empty); this works, but how to manage the ? before qt?

Comment: I try to insert ? after/select/ , like this: var counter = 1;
            foreach (var url in urlList)
            {
                try
                {
                    stopwatch.Start();
                    requester.DownloadString(url);
                    url.Replace("\n",string.Empty);
                    if (url.Contains("/select/"))
                    {
                        url.Replace(string.Empty, "?");
                    }


                }

Comment: @SavantKing Is there any reason you can't add the *?* into the source text file directly?  If not, looking at the source, you should be able to replace the space with a *?*.